# Replace all “?” by “&” except first

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I’d would to replace all “?” by “&” except the first one by javascript. I found some regular expressions but they didn’t work.
I have something like:

```
home/?a=1
home/?a=1?b=2
home/?a=1?b=2?c=3
```

And I would like:

```
home/?a=1
home/?a=1&b=2
home/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Someone know how to I can do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the form of the input? Do you have a string with a single path? Do you have text file with a path on each line? Do you actually want to change the URL of the current page? Please elaborate.

Comment: To those voted as a duplicate: which of those answers do you consider using? The checked answer is irrelevant, the other answers allocate too much.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I did it with a regex, see the answer below

Comment: I meant with regex sensibly :P

Comment: @AdamMillerchip right, but splitting solely to join it back immediately looks wasteful and non-semantic: the task being solved is to replace a string in the end of the day :shrug:

Comment: Oh, I thought clicking on `reopen` would put it on a vote, not instantly reopen it back, sorry! Nevertheless I think duplicate should be reconsidered, they share very little in common.

Comment: What do you want to do with `home?a=1?b=2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with regex but you can split the string and then join it back together, manually replacing the first occurance:

```js
var split = 'home/?a=1?b=2'.split('?'); // [ 'home/', 'a=1', 'b=2' ]
var replaced = split[0] + '?' + split.slice(1).join('&') // 'home/?a=1&b=2'
console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match from the start of the string not a question mark using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^?]+` followed by matching a question mark and capture that in the first capturing group. In the second capturing group capture the rest of the string.

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and pass a function as the second parameter where you return the first capturing group followed by the second capturing group where all the question marks are replaced by `&`

```js
let strings = [
  "home/?a=1",
  "home/?a=1?b=2",
  "home/?a=1?b=2?c=3"
];

strings.forEach((str) => {
  let result = str.replace(/(^[^?]+\?)(.*)/, function(match, group1, group2) {
    return group1 + group2.replace(/\?/g, '&')
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it by "?" and then rewrap the array:

```
var string = "home/?a=1?b=2";
var str = string.split('?');

var new = str[0] + '?'; // text before first '?' and first '?'

for( var x = 1; x < str.length; x++ ) {
    new = new + str[x];
    if( x != ( str.length - 1 ) ) new = new + '&'; //to avoid place a '&' after the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/([^\/])\?/` as pattern in regex that match any `?` character that isn't after `/` character.

```
var str = str.replace(/([^\/])\?/g, "$1&");
```

```js
var str = "home/?a=1\nhome/?a=1?b=2\nhome/?a=1?b=2?c=3\n".replace(/([^\/])\?/g, "$1&");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: When I run this snippet, I get `"SyntaxError: invalid regexp group"`. Javascript doesn't understand lookbehind.

Comment: @Toto Problem fixed

Comment: It works. But I'll give you my vote when OP'll say what to do with `home?a=1?b=1`

Comment: @Toto Your right, but this is answer for this structure string. If structure changed, user should mentioned in question (structure changed or maybe change) or use answer that match with it.